# Can't install Strongloop for Loopback v.3 on MacOS Catalina

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to learn about Loopback v3 (which is what they are using on a job site where I'm working), and I'm trying to follow their tutorials.  One of the steps is to install Strongloop

`npm i -g strongloop`

but it keeps failing with these errors (among others):

> static void SetMessageHandler(Isolate* isolate,
>      ^ 5 warnings and 4 errors generated. make: *** [Release/obj.target/debugger/src/controller.o] Error 1 gyp ERR! build
>   error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23) gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0 gyp ERR! command
>   "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/bin/node"
>   "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-debugger
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok

This install attempt was Node v.8, but I tried it with Node v.12 first and that didn't work either.

I thought I'd try to go on and ignore the errors, but when I get to the ´datasource´section of the tutorial  (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-data-sources.html), it fails, which I suppose is because Strongloop was not correctly installed.

> The new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option {
>   useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor. Web server
>   listening at: http://localhost:3000 Browse your REST API at
>   http://localhost:3000/explorer events.js:187
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read Emitted 'error'
>   event on DataSource instance at:

It's frustrating, as I don't know what to do to get Strongloop to install correctly.  Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Its a permission error

Comment: @Sachin Yadav -- Yes, but of what?  I tried changing the e

Comment: Permissions of the directory the project was in, as well as those of the server directory.

Comment: EISDIR stands for "Error, Is Directory". This means that NPM is trying to do something to a file but it is a directory. In your case, NPM is trying to "read" a file which is a directory.Since the operation cannot be done the error is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to learn about Loopback v3 (which is what they are using on a job site where I'm working), and I'm trying to follow their tutorials. One of the steps is to install Strongloop

StrongLoop CLI is not necessary for LoopBack development. It has been deprecated in favor of smaller & focused tools.

You can find an up-to-date tutorial for starting with LoopBack here: https://loopback.io/lb3/getting-started

The most important part is to install `loopback-cli` instead of `strongloop`:

```
$ npm install -g loopback-cli
```

IIRC, this package does not have any native dependencies requiring compilation, therefore you should not encounter any build errors from `gyp`.